# Why does my Ansible task hang?

Tags: ansible

I have the following ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: node1
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: update apt
    apt: update_cache=yes
  - name: install python-setuptools
    apt: name=python-setuptools update_cache=yes
  - name: easy_install pexpect module
    easy_install: name=pexpect state=latest
  - name: add geonode repo
    apt_repository: repo='ppa:geonode/stable' state=present
  - name: update apt
    apt: update_cache=yes
  - name: install geonode
    apt: name=geonode update_cache=yes
  - expect:
        command: geonode createsuperuser
        responses:
          (?i)username: 'test'
          (?i)email: 'test@test.com'
```

When I run it I get:

```
PLAY [node1] *******************************************************************

TASK [update apt] **************************************************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [install python-setuptools] ***********************************************
changed: [node1]

TASK [easy_install pexpect module] *********************************************
changed: [node1]

TASK [add geonode repo] ********************************************************
changed: [node1]

TASK [update apt] **************************************************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [install geonode] *********************************************************
```

Then it hangs indefinitely. 
In the remote node (node1), I checked the dir

> /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470059145.13-122191240803512/

run the file inside to see why my task is hanging

> vagrant@node1:~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1470059145.13-122191240803512$ python apt

and get:

```
{"msg": "Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"dpkg_options": "force-confdef,force-confold", "autoremove": false, "force": false, "name": "geonode", "install_recommends": null, "package": ["geonode"], "purge": false, "allow_unauthenticated": false, "state": "present", "upgrade": null, "update_cache": true, "default_release": null, "only_upgrade": false, "deb": null, "cache_valid_time": null}}}
```

Do you have any insights?

**EDIT 1:**

It is all day I'm launching this script and never got it working. As I posted this question, obviously, the script successfully executed till the end in 15 minutes. I launched it before lunch today and after 1 hour it was still hanging. Why do I get such a different behaviour? Is there a way in which I can control it?

Comment: Could it be that another `apt` command is also running on the system (not triggered from this playbook) that has already acquired the lock?

Comment: No, no other apt running..

Comment: Side note: There is no need to run `update_cache=yes` multiple times. It is not the problem here, but it slows down your playbook. Every time you run `update_cache=yes` Ansible will run `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue might be caused by an empty `/var/lib/apt folder`.

Vagrant might take a while to populate these folders which could cause the apt lock.

Also the playbook is inefficient as `update_cache` is used multiple times. I would recommend to use something like this:

```
- hosts: node1
  sudo: yes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    # Pause for 5 minutes to make sure vagrant does not hold apt lock.
    - pause:
        minutes: 5

    - name: add geonode repo
      apt_repository:
        repo: 'ppa:geonode/stable'
        state: present

    - name: Install apt packages.
      apt:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
        update_cache: true
      with_items:
        - python-setuptools
        - geonode

  - name: Create geonode superuser.
    expect:
      command: geonode createsuperuser
      responses:
        (?i)username: 'test'
        (?i)email: 'test@test.com'
```

This way Ansible won't update the repositories multiple times during the play.

Answer (score 0):

Since the last thing you see is `TASK [install geonode]`, that's where it's getting stuck.

You are asking it to run `geonode createsuperuser` which you expect to cause a prompt for username and password.

But what is likely happening is that there is an error being produced from that command, and the `expect` task is not handling the error, instead just hanging.

You can login to the server you are running this against and run the `geonode createsuperuser` command manually to see what error is being produced.

In my case, this was happening as a result of the username already being taken since I successfully ran the command on this machine already.

`Error: That username is already taken.`

Even with the `echo: yes` argument, ansible doesn't seem to pass on the responses to make it obvious what's happening.  And it doesn't accept `ignore_errors`, so there seems to be no way to handle errors with the `expect` module.

To work around this, I added another task after the createsuperuser task which places a file in the project indicating the user was created once, and then added `creates: {{ path }}/superuser_exists.txt` to the `createsuperuser` task so that it won't run if that file is already there.

It's a hack, but an easy one, and until the module gets better error handling, it will work well enough.

```
- name: Create the django superuser
  expect:
    command: "{{ virtualenv_path }}/bin/python3 {{ project_path }}/{{ api_app_name }}/manage.py createsuperuser"
    creates: "{{ project_path }}/{{ api_app_name }}/superuser_exists.txt"
    responses:
      (?i)username: "{{ superuser_username }}"
      (?i)email: "{{ superuser_email }}"
      (?i)password: "{{ superuser_password }}"
      (?i)again: "{{ superuser_password }}"

- name: Create a file to indicate that the superuser was already created
  file: path="{{ project_path }}/{{ api_app_name }}/superuser_exists.txt" state=touch
```